# create vertical large table

Tags: tables, vertical

I am trying to create the following table, but it out of page bounds

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l*{16}{|c}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{ }} & \multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\textbf{Benchmark}} & \multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\textbf{Graduate}} & \multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\textbf{Our Approach}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{metric}} & \textbf{Acc.} & \textbf{P. (FR)}& \textbf{P (NFR)}  & \textbf{R.(FR)} & \textbf {R. (FR) } & \textbf{Acc.} & \textbf{P. (FR)} & \textbf{P. (NFR)}  & \textbf{R.(FR)}  & \textbf{R. (FR) } & \textbf{Acc.} & \textbf{P. (FR)} & \textbf{P (NFR)}  & \textbf{R.(FR)}  & \textbf{R. (FR) }   \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Case\#1}} & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 93\% & 90\% & 93.8\% & 94\% & 90\% & 95\% & 91\% & 100\% & 100\% & 90\% \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Case\#2}} &  100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 86\% & 82\% & 90\% & 92\% & 80\% & 85\% & 100\% & 76\% & 70\% & 100\% \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Case\#3}} & 100\% & 100\% & 100\%
& 100\% & 100\% & 91\% & 93\% & 88.6\% & 88\% & 94\% & 90\% & 88\% & 81\% & 80\% & 90\% \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\textbf{Average}} & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 90\% & 88.3\% & 90.8\% & 91.3\% & 88\% & 90\% & 93\% & 85.66\% & 83.33\% & 93.33\% \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

[image: The Table]

Comment: Your table code does not produce showed image (different number of column, different text in cells, etc.). What you after? To reproduce shoed image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To long for the comment.

Provided code fragment is not even close what is shown on image. Combinig bot the closet to what is on image is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l | C|C|C|C | C|C|C|C|}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Benchmark}
        & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Graduate}                        \\
    \cline{2-9}
%    & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Our Approach} &                     \\ 
%    \cline{11-15}
    & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Accuracy}
            & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Precision (FR)} 
                    & \multicolumn{2}{|c|} {Precision (NFR)} 
                            & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Recall (FR)}  \\ 
    \hline
1\textsuperscript{st} - party cookies
    & 29 & 17 & 27 & 20 & 93 &    &    &                        \\ 
    \hline
1\textsuperscript{st}/3\textsuperscript{rd} party cookies
    & 19 & 22 & 23 & 20 & 84 &    &    &                        \\ 
    \hline
Total
    & 48 & 39 & 50 & 40 &177 &    &    &                        \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Number of respondants for treatment}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, edit your question and instead of code fragment provide a small but complete document, which can be compiled and which reproduce your problem (protrude out of page, if U understand you correctly.

**Addendum:**
Finally you provide complete table code fragment. Unfortunately is still unknown page layout, which is essential for your table design. How much space is available for table? Who knows?

I assume, that page layout is determined by `\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}`. If not, than you will hew new troubles ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
    \sisetup{table-align-text-after=false}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[l, font=\small\bfseries] 
                        *{5}{X[0.9,c,m, si={table-format=3.0{\%}}]}
                        *{5}{X[    c,m, si={table-format=3.1{\%}}]}
                        *{5}{X[1.1,c,m, si={table-format=3.2{\%}}]}},
             colsep  = 3pt,
            row{1,2} = {font=\small\bfseries},
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    
    &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}  {{{Benchmark}}} &   &   &   &   
        &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}  {{{Graduate}}}  &   &   &   &    
            &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}  {{{Our Approach}}}    &   &   &   &               \\ 
metric  
    & {{{Acc.}}} & {{{P. (FR)}}} & {{{P. (NFR)}}} & {{{R. (FR)}}} & {{{R. (FR)}}}
    & {{{Acc.}}} & {{{P. (FR)}}} & {{{P. (NFR)}}} & {{{R. (FR)}}} & {{{R. (FR)}}}
    & {{{Acc.}}} & {{{P.\\ (FR)}}} & {{{P. (NFR)}}} & {{{R.\\ (FR)}}} & {{{R.\\ (FR)}}}   \\
%
Case\#1 & 100\% & 100\%     & 100\%     & 100\%     & 100\% 
        &  93\% &  90\%     &  93.8\%   &  94\%     &  90\% 
        &  95\% &  91\%     & 100\%     & 100\%     &  90\%     \\
Case\#2 & 100\% & 100\%     & 100\%     & 100\%     & 100\% 
        &  86\% &  82\%     &  90\%     &  92\%     &  80\% 
        &  85\% & 100\%     &  76\%     &  70\%     & 100\%     \\
Case\#3 & 100\% & 100\%     & 100\%     & 100\%     & 100\% 
        &  91\% &  93\%     &  88.6\%   &  88\%     &  94\% 
        &  90\% &  88\%     &  81\%     &  80\%     &  90\%     \\
Average & 100\% & 100\%     & 100\%     & 100\%     & 100\% 
        &  90\% &  88.3\%   &  90.8\%   &  91.3\%   &  88\% 
        &  90\% &  93\%     & 85.66\%   &  83.33\%  &  93.33\%  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{sidewaystable} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I edit my code, now my problem is the table is out of the page margen 
how can I resize it?

Comment: Meanwhile your question become duplicate. In given lik to answer are enumerated all possibilities what to do. Do you try something?

Comment: I tried code at this question But I git a new problem!  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643256/how-to-resize-a-very-long-table-in-latex?noredirect=1#comment1603045_643256

Comment: @Eng.sh, see addendum to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's work!