# How to resize a very wide table in latex

Tags: tables

I created the following table in `LaTeX` but it was too wide to fit on the page, even in landscape format. How can I solve this problem? The code is:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l*{16}{|c}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{ }} & \multicolumn{5}{|m{5cm}|}{\textbf{Benchmark}} & \multicolumn{5}{|m{5cm}|}{\textbf{Graduate}} & \multicolumn{5}{|m{5cm}|}{\textbf{Our Approach}} \\ \hline \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{metric}} & \textbf{Acc.} & \textbf{P.(FR)}& \textbf{P.(NFR)}  & \textbf{R.(FR)} & \textbf {R.(FR) } & \textbf{Acc.} & \textbf{P. (FR)} & \textbf{P. (NFR)}  & \textbf{R.(FR)}  & \textbf{R. (FR) } & \textbf{Acc.} & \textbf{P. (FR)} & \textbf{P. (NFR)}  & \textbf{R.(FR)}  & \textbf{R. (FR) }   \\ \hline 

\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Case\#1}} & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 93\% & 90\% & 93.8\% & 94\% & 90\% & 95\% & 91\% & 100\% & 100\% & 90\% \\ \hline 

\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Case\#2}} &  100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 86\% & 82\% & 90\% & 92\% & 80\% & 85\% & 100\% & 76\% & 70\% & 100\% \\ \hline 

\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Case\#3}} & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 91\% & 93\% & 88.6\% & 88\% & 94\% & 90\% & 88\% & 81\% & 80\% & 90\% \\ \hline 

\multicolumn{1}{|p{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Average}} & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 90\% & 88.3\% & 90.8\% & 91.3\% & 88\% & 90\% & 93\% & 85.66\% & 83.33\% & 93.33\% \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

[image: the output]

Comment: Please add compilable examples.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke i add the output of the code , the table is  out of the page

Comment: Do you really expect any reader to actually read that? Might be a better idea to rethink / redesign your tables.

Comment: Do you mean I have to partition it?

Comment: Which document class do you employ? How tall and wide is the textblock? What's the main font size?

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

Comment: I would split it into more than one tabular.

Answer (score 3):

Why not divide your table into three almost identical parts?

```
\begin{tabular}{|l*{5}{|c}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{5}{|m{5cm}|}{\textbf{Benchmark}} \\ \hline \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{metric}} & \textbf{Acc.} & \textbf{P.(FR)}& \textbf{P.(NFR)}  & \textbf{R.(FR)} & \textbf {R.(FR) } \\ \hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Case\#1}}&  95\% & 91\%  & 100\%   & 100\%   & 90\% \\ \hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Case\#2}}&  85\% & 100\% & 76\%    & 70\%    & 100\% \\ \hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Case\#3}}&  90\% & 88\%  & 81\%    & 80\%    & 90\% \\ \hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|p{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Average}}&  90\% & 93\%  & 85.66\% & 83.33\% & 93.33\% \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{6}{c}{}\\
  \multicolumn{6}{c}{}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{5}{|m{5cm}|}{\textbf{Graduate}} \\ \hline \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{metric}} & \textbf{Acc.} & \textbf{P.(FR)}& \textbf{P.(NFR)}  & \textbf{R.(FR)} & \textbf {R.(FR) }   \\ \hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Case\#1}} & 100\%  & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% \\ \hline  
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Case\#2}} &  100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\%  \\ \hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Case\#3}} & 100\%  & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% \\ \hline  
\multicolumn{1}{|p{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Average}} & 100\%  & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 100\%  \\ \hline 
\multicolumn{6}{c}{}\\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{}\\
\hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{}}& \multicolumn{5}{|m{5cm}|}{\textbf{Our Approach}} \\ \hline \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{metric}} & \textbf{Acc.} & \textbf{P.(FR)}& \textbf{P.(NFR)}  & \textbf{R.(FR)} & \textbf {R.(FR) } \\ \hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Case\#1}}&  93\%  & 90\%   & 93.8\% & 94\%   & 90\%  \\ \hline  
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Case\#2}}&   86\% & 82\%   & 90\%   & 92\%   & 80\%   \\ \hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Case\#3}}&  91\%  & 93\%   & 88.6\% & 88\%   & 94\%  \\ \hline  
\multicolumn{1}{|p{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Average}}&  90\%  & 88.3\% & 90.8\% & 91.3\% & 88\%   \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

[image: Tableaux]